# Match MD5 passwords in PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, md5

```
$json=file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

$email=$obj->{"email_id"};
$pwd=md5($obj->{"pwd"});
$sql_login="Select email,password from bar_details where bar_email='$email' and bar_password='$pwd'";

$result_login=mysql_query($sql_login);

$num=mysql_num_rows($result_login);
```

Always get value of $num=0.I even checked the query on mysql it returns zero rows. The passwords are stored in MD5 format.

Comment: your SQL is prone to SQL injections and using md5 for password hashing isn't safe annymore

Comment: MD5 is considered broken for security purposes and is not sufficient for password hashing. Use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: As the others have said, you shouldn't use these functions. Yet to debug this problem further I'd check if you stored the password correctly and are typing the right password.